# i am getting an out of memory error only when i try to add the name to this chart

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

i have a sub which will create a chart onto a sheet, when i try to add the name to the chart with .name it gives me an error "out of memory". i have tried to add it inside the with block but the same error and i also tried with different name instead of hi but still the same thing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub addchartv4()
Dim chart As chart
Dim xRg As Range
 Dim chartdatarange As Range, chartExists As Boolean
 
 Set chartdatarange = Worksheets("count_issue").Range("a3:c17")
 
 
' chartexists = False
' For Each Chart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
'    If Chart.Name = "issue_count" Then
'        chartexists = True
'        Exit For
'    End If
'
' Next Chart
'
Set chart = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set chart = Worksheets("chart11").ChartObjects
On Error GoTo 0


 If chart Is Nothing Then
 
 Set chart = Worksheets("chart11").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("a1").Left, Top:=Range("a1").Top, Width:=400, Height:=300).chart
 chart.Name = "hi"
 With chart
    
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SetSourceData Source:=chartdatarange
    ', PlotBy:=xlColumns
    
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = chartdatarange.Columns(1)
    
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "issue_count"
    .HasLegend = False
    .SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd
    
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone
    
    
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone
    

    
    End With
    End If
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name the chart, but the chartObject.

The ChartObject is the container for the chart (and is part of the `Shapes`-collection of a worksheet. Inside the `ChartObject` you have the `Chart`-property which defines the real chart. You cannot name the chart, you can only name the `ChartObject`. The chart has automatic generated name (containing sheet + chartObject name). Trying to set the name manually leads to this "Out of Memory" error (which is just a symptom that something failed).

Now the fix is simple, but you have another issue in your code: When you check if the sheet contains already a chart(object), with the command `Set chart = Worksheets("chart11").ChartObjects` you try to assign a `chartObjects`-collection to a `chart` variable. This will fail in any case with a "Type mismatch". As you enclosed the command with `On Error Resume Next`, it will look as if there is never a chart on that worksheet and every time a new chart is created.

If you always have only one chart on the sheet, you could change the code to

```
' Check if there is already a chart on the sheet
If Worksheets("chart11").ChartObjects.Count > 0 then Exit Sub 
Dim co as ChartObject
With Worksheets("chart11")
    ' Create a new Chart
    Set co = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=.Range("a1").Left, Top:=.Range("a1").Top, Width:=400, Height:=300)
    co.Name = "hi"
    Debug.Print co.Name, co.Chart.Name   ' <-- You will see "Hi    chart11 Hi"
End With

With co.Chart
    ...(Do your chart magic here)
End With
```

If you want to check if the chart "Hi" already exists, use

```
Dim co As ChartObject
On Error Resume Next
' Check if Chart "Hi" already exists
Set co = Worksheets("chart11").ChartObjects("Hi")
If Not co Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
```